# Solidity ParserError: Expected ';' but got '{'

Tags: solidity

Using Version `0.6.0`

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract Test {
    function sendValue(address payable recipient, uint256 amount) external {
        (bool success, ) = recipient.call{ value: amount }("");
    }
}
```

> Test.sol:5:42: ParserError: Expected ';' but got '{' (bool success, ) = recipient.call{ value: amount }(""); ^

Why is this error here?

Answer (score 7):

You're using syntax that was introduced in Solidity 0.7 but isn't yet valid in 0.6.

For 0.6, use this:

```
(bool success, ) = recipient.call.value(amount)("");
```

Sources and more info:

- 0.7 syntax: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.7.0/control-structures.html#external-function-calls
- 0.6 syntax: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.6.0/control-structures.html#external-function-calls

Answer (score 1):

add this to the top of your code

```
pragma solodity >= 0.6.0 < 0.9.0;
```

This will support syntax above 0.6 and below 0.9

Comment: solidity :D ....