# solidity: ParserError: Expected ';' but got '('

Tags: blockchain, solidity

1. first of all.I want to check what "solidity: ParserError: Expected ';' but got '('" want to express.
2. How can I improve my code to pass it?

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0<0.9.0;

contract Withdraw{
    constructor()payable{}
    fucntion withdrawByTransfer() public {
        paybale(msg.sender).transfer(1 ether);
    }

    fucntion withdrawBySend()public{
        bool success = paybale(msg.sender).send(1 eth);
        require(succeess);
    }

    fucntion withdrawByCall() public returns(bytes memory){
        (bool succeess,bytes memory result) = payable(msg.sender).call{value: require(success)};

        return result;
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xxME.png)
some ref
[Solidity ParserError: Expected ';' but got '{'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66388642/solidity-parsererror-expected-but-got)

[Solidity - ParserError: Expected ';' but got '['](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71321709/solidity-parsererror-expected-but-got)

Comment: you have too many typos: function, payable, success

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

First fix your typos function and payable are keywords typos are not tolerated. this will fix the expected ; error

Secondly, a significant problem lies in your 3rd function. A basic rule in programming is the right side of the expression gets executed first, so in this line

```
(bool success,bytes memory result) = payable(msg.sender).call{value: require(success)};
```

success in the require statement is not visible since it has not been initialized with a value yet.
but even if success does have a value the argument 'value' does not accept a require statement as a value here is how you fix it.

```
function withdrawByCall(uint256 _amount) public payable returns(bytes memory){
        (bool success,bytes memory result) = payable(msg.sender).call{value: _amount}(" ");
        require(success);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Does the `withdrawByCall()` function work?
`msg.value` means the `msg.sender` sends `msg.value` amount of ether to the contract.
Then, in the `withdrawByCall()` function, it sends `msg.value` amount of ether to the `msg.sender`
Finally, it means no ether moves and only cast gas?

Comment: my bad, what you need to do is introduce a parameter in which the caller specifies the amount and that amount is withdrawn

Answer (score 0):

Here is the completed code

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0<0.9.0;

contract Withdraw {
    constructor() payable {}

    function withdrawByTransfer(uint256 amount) public payable {
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(amount);
    }

    function withdrawBySend(uint256 amount) public payable {
        bool success = payable(msg.sender).send(amount);
        require(success, "Failed to send Ether");
    }

    function withdrawByCall(uint256 amount) public returns(bytes memory) {
        (bool success, bytes memory result) = payable(msg.sender).call{value: amount}("");
        require(success, "Failed to withdraw Ether");

        return result;
    }
}
```