# Why is the 'truffle compile' command failing and how can this be resolved?

Tags: solidity

I recently started learning Solidity via YouTube. I'm currently trying to code my first ERC-721 token. I'm following this video and got stuck at around minute 25: [How to Code a Crypto Collectible: ERC-721 NFT Tutorial (Ethereum)](https://youtube.com/watch?v=YPbgjPPC1d0&t=1503s)

At this minute he is trying to compile his project using truffle, at least that's what I understand. When I try to compile, I keep getting the following error message:

```
C:\starter_kit>truffle compile
Error parsing C:/starter_kit/src/contracts/ERC721.sol: ParsedContract.sol:295:42: ParserError: Expected ';' but got '{'
    (bool success, ) = recipient.call{value: amount}("");

Compilation failed. See above.
Truffle v5.0.5 (core: 5.0.5)
Node v18.7.0
```

The file to which the error message is referring, is from this location:
[OpenZeppelin / openzeppelin-contracts](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts) and is located in the following folder: "openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/token/ERC721/"

The above is what the person who created the tutorial also uses. Although it seems like the video is outdated and the openzeppelin files are more recent, I believe eventually this shouldn't be a problem with some adjustments. However, it will probably have something to do with the error message.

I tried to go into the 'ERC721.sol' file and edit some code, but as I'm only just starting I don't really know where to look at and what to change. Is it possible to help with this? I would really like to continue learning Solidity, as I think there's a future for this.

Any help is very much appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you are using syntax that is for latest solidity version 0.6.0>

use this instead

```
(bool success, ) = recipient.call.value(amount)("");
```

[Solidity ParserError: Expected ';' but got '{'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66388642/solidity-parsererror-expected-but-got)